# SpringBoot REST Api JSON validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-rest

I have a simple springboot app with one Rest api. I want to validate the request parameters are not null/empty. I convert the json into a java object and from here I want to validate they have all the required fields and are not null or not empty.(The object is not getting saved to db)
I am currently using javax validation methods without any success.

```
@RestController
public class GardenController{

@PostMapping(value = "/submit")
public ResponseEntity submit(
        @RequestPart(value="garden", required=true) Garden garden
) throws Exception { 
}
}

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.util.Arrays;


@Getter
@Setter
public class Garden{

public Garden( String[] address, String area, String location, Feature
feature) {
    this.address= address;
    this.area= area;
    this.location= location;
    this.feature= feature;
}

public Garden() {
}

@JsonProperty("address")
@NotEmpty(message = "address is required")
private String [] address = null;

@JsonProperty("area")
@NotEmpty(message = "area is required")
private String area= null;

@JsonProperty("location")
@NotEmpty(message = "location is required")
private String location= null;

@JsonProperty("feature")
@NotEmpty(message = "feature is required")
private Feature feature= null;
```

I also have a contained Feature class that I need to be validated( all fields required and not null or empty)

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Feature {

public Feature () {
}

public Feature (String construction, String type) {
    this.construction = construction;
    this.type = type;
}

@NotEmpty(message = "construction is required")
private String construction;

@NotEmpty(message = "type is required")
private String type;

}
```

Comment: In your controller method try adding `@Valid` before Garden. Also try adding `@Validated` to your controller class.

Comment: You need to instruct Spring MVC to validate your object, you will need to add `@Valid` to your method argument (next to `@RequestPart`). To validate embedded objects you need to add `@Valid` to the field as well. You don't need `@Validated` on your controller (as suggested by @pirho) that serves a different purpose.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum, that worked. However I am getting 400 response but not with the message I had set:  {
    "timestamp": "2020-07-01T09:43:58.052+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "", }

Comment: Because that is a generic 400 message when things go wrong. If you want more detailed information you need to add your own exception handling.

Comment: so if the  message is not fed into the HTTP Response message, then where is it used?

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate the controller class as @Validated and add @Valid annotation to the request parameter:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.Valid;
// ...
@RestController
@Validated
public class GardenController{

    @PostMapping(value = "/submit")
    public ResponseEntity submit(
        @RequestPart(value="garden", required=true) @Valid Garden garden
    ) throws Exception { 
    }
}
```